# how can I check if Leiningen is successfully installed and working at full capacity?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

Java JDK is installed, everything works great, also maven works great.

I followed the instructions from the site, downloaded the bat file, set the path and at the command prompt started the installation with the command lein self-install.

what i got in response is downloading leiningen now ....

after a while, C: \ windows \ system32> appeared below that line and it stays that way for several hours.

What more should I do?

Comment: I don't know the Clojure setup for Windows but common sense would dictate that the batch file has finished, and if there is no error to be seen, it is likely the setup was successful. Check in your start menu whether there is a specific submenu/-item for starting a shell with Clojure in the path; if so, use that, otherwise just open a CMD, and enter `lein repl` to check if the REPL is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The command line normally uses a prompt like `>` or similar to indicate it is waiting for a command.  Then you type something followed by the `<return>` key:

```
> lein --version
Leiningen 2.9.8 on Java 1.8.0_322 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>
```

Here I typed `lein --version`, then `<ret>`, and the computer responded with a 1-liner about the version of Leiningen and Java that are installed. Then it displayed the prompt again, waiting for the next command.

You can use the `cd` (change directory) command to move around. With no prompt it will send you back to your "home" directory.  See docs for the BASH or ZSH shell.

For Windows, I highly recommend installing the BASH Shell and `git` from this site:

https://gitforwindows.org/

IMHO the `bash` shell is greatly superior to the built-in Windows shell from `CMD.EXE`